# Include null values or space in tokenize() groovy

Tags: groovy, null, soapui, space, tokenize

In a SoapUi's groovy script, I would like to tokenize a csv like file as follow:

Data:

```
Value1;Value2;;Value3

//Or witha  sapce
Value1;Value2; ;Value3
```

and have something like:

```
[Value1,Value2,null,Value3]

//Or
[Value1,Value2, ,Value3]
```

I used:

```
tokenize(';')
```

But I only get

```
[Value1,Value2,Value3]
```

Where the null and space value are ignored.

How can I do that?

Comment: You could always use a [CSV parser](http://xlson.com/groovycsv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `split`:

```
assert ['Value1', 'Value2', '', 'Value3'] == 'Value1;Value2;;Value3'.split(';')
```